# How to avoid the API tracing from proxy server and Proxy tools such as fiddler

Tags: api, security, proxy, server

I am using Fiddler tool and iam getting API request and responce with parameter even thought its HTTPS web application . How to avoid this, I dont want show my API request and header by using any tool of proxies. Can you some one guide me

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

Your API is called from the client. Anything on the client is controlled by the owner of such client, ie. your enduser. He may choose to run the client side of your application as your server sends it (the normal way most people do :) ), or he may decide to investigate, understand or modify any client-side code. This obviously includes getting to know your API as well.

To put it another way, the client (ie. the application in the client browser) needs to know how to talk to the API. But the client browser with the application is fully controlled by the client user, so he will also have this knowledge.

The good thing is, **you have no reason to hide your API structure**. If security is implemented properly, your API endpoints and calls can be public and your application will still be secure.

As a sidenote, HTTPS doesn't help here. Think of HTTPS as a tunnel, nobody can look through the walls, but anybody can look into the tunnel at both ends. One end is your server, but the other is the client. So Fiddler installed on the client can look into HTTPS traffic from/to that client (it is actually a little bit more complex, but let's go with this for now). However, Fiddler or anything else cannot look into HTTPS traffic between endpoints the Fiddler user doesn't control (again, this is somewhat simplified). So in short, HTTPS is secure if configured correctly, but it only secures the channel, and endpoints are out of scope for HTTPS.

Comment: If Fiddler provides the https request and parameters, any use can (Crakers)  take the api and create load to the server and crack the server, So i dont want to show my api request or parameters to anyone using the any of the tools

Comment: Your goal when writing your server-side code and creating your architecture is making this hard enough. With proper security (most importantly, adequate authentication and authorization on the server side), it will be very hard to "crack the server", and with the right architecture and measures which are way beyond the code, it will be hard to perform a successful DoS attack as well. So in short, don't implement security by obscurity; instead, create a robust architecture and write secure code on the server - that way, there is no harm in having a public API, which you can't avoid anyway.

Comment: authentication and authorization key also can get using fiddler. I have checked the Facebook and other applications which is popular, In those applications, when we connect Proxy server, they are disconnecting network internally which means use can not send the api request and perform the actions, One of the proxy tool is "Charles" for using the charles we can get any api it will shows us unknown instead of api, But fidler is advance option and if i enable https encryption i getting api and parameters

Comment: Facebook is a great example of a public API. It's very well documented even. :) It is using certificate pinning though, making it harder to use an intermediate proxy, but that is not the purpose, and that doesn't stop an attacker from getting to know the API even if was undocumented. I'm afraid I can't help you sorry, but again, it is not possible to hide your API due to the reasons detailed in my answer.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the info. can you check below screen shot from Charles 
http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvXmh8.jpg  . Here Fb api is showing but content is hiding, But my application api and content and showing. can you suggest me is the my web application is secure  http://f6.s.qip.ru/cMfvXmhn.jpg